# Java EE app without database but exe and txt files

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, jakarta-ee

I have to make a Java EE application

First tier : client web
Second tier : server Java EE
Third tier : exe,  txt files

we can have many clients connected at the same time , the problem is that 2+ clients cant launch exe at the same time, second client have to wait first client.....etc
We can do the job if we use Thread, but in Java EE is not recommanded to use threads

so client launch exe file, and this exe generate txt file and we have to read this txt and send some information to client (generate for each client, one txt file )

Sometimes one client can send a request that call exe three times , and you know, we must await the end of each exe's treatment to call exe again.

- Client 1 request (call exe 3 times) 
  **- (1)-exe-> client1 directory txt01.txt**
  *- wait the end of exe treatment (long treatment)*
  **- (2)-exe-> client1 directory txt02.txt**
  *- wait the end of exe treatment (long treatment)*
  **- (3)-exe-> client1 directory txt02.txt**
- Client 2 request (call exe 1 time) **-exe->  client2 directory txt01.txt** *(wait the end of exe treatment if it is launched by another client)*

.......

Comment: I'm not seeing a question in there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do the work asynchronously.

Setup an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with only one Thread and submit jobs to it that call the .exe and generate the text file.
Use AJAX on the web site to poll the site for when the file/files are ready, then just deliver the file to the user.

I hope this helps.

Comment: we dont need AJAX, we will read txt file and send the first line for example to client .....

Comment: You can't use Threads in your EJB, but I don't really see a problem with using them within a J2EE application in general.

Comment: can we do that with servlet 3.0 ? asynch processing ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean 2+ clients shouldn't access the EXE or they just fail to do it? Anyway 1st case, I'm guessing you got a stateless bean in the server, try to make it a "state machine" with the states of number of clients. 2nd case, I don't see why the clients should fail accessing the EXE together? It's probably a configuration you can change when you create it (how did u create the exe by the way?)
But yes, like guys here said don't mess with threads in there.